# Is there a download manager which can retrieve automatically an URL from a RSS feed?

Tags: download

Is there a download manager which can retrieve automatically a URL from an RSS feed, or an XML file, or even a text or HTML file (any of these options is fine)? If yes how can I configure it?

I (or other people, or just software) will add new downloads to a given file, it can be xml, I want the download manager to check REGULARLY and AUTOMATICALLY this file, check if the file with this link was downloaded before, and if it was not, download it automatically - yes, the key here is automation.

Probably important: the device is a Raspberry Pi